# List view's getChildCount method does not return an accurate count of the number of visible items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need to be able to tell which items in a list view are visible. The "[visibleItemCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)" term in onScroll and the [listview.getChildCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29) both return values that are typically 1-3 higher than they should be based on what is actually visible on the screen. The items are not necessarily the same height which might play a role in throwing this off.

What would be the best way to get a more accurate reading of what is visible?

Comment: do you use the correct way to re-use views , using the convertView? weird things can happen if you always create a new view in the getView method. also, is it possible that your listview is behind another view?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getChildCount()` is not supposed to return the count of visible childs but, as the docs say :

> Returns the number of children in the group.

To get the number of visible items you should probably be using [`getLastVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) and [`getFirstVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) :

```
int visibleChildsCount=lv.getLastVisiblePosition()-lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: I'm trying these as well and they also return erroneous values. getFirstVisiblePosition() correctly gets the first one visible in the top of the box, but getLastVisiblePosition, like the other methods, returns the index of an item that is one to three positions below the bottom of the view box.

Comment: The problem with this is that visible items can be partially visible. F.e. the last item in your list get counted to visible items even if there's only 1 pixel height in it. So `getLastVisiblePosition()` always returns the partially visible item in your list.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't explain [the behaviour I'm seeing](http://i.imgur.com/0P5pFiY.png). At this point, I'm looking into solutions to manually check the locations of the items that are claiming to be visible from the bottom up and uncount the ones that actually are not.